# Use variable's value in DriveApp searchFiles query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I may have silly question but I can't find a solution

I have go through a lot of files in my google drive and inside every file there is a number within 0-10000 range, so I made this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
  var test = "IT" + i;
  Logger.log(test);
  var search = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID")
                       .searchFiles('fullText contains test');
  Logger.log(search);
  while (search.hasNext()) {
    var file = search.next();
    if(search.hasNext())
      break;
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
  ...
```

My question is, how can I put a variable like this:

```
.searchFiles('fullText contains $variable');
```

so that I can use the value of the variable `test`, i.e. "IT0", rather than the literal string `test`?

Comment: `.searchFiles('fullText contains ' + yourVariable);`

Comment: Tried Your way and `searchFiles('fullText contains "IT"' + test)` - Didn't work. I am getting error: Invalid argument: q (line 18, file "test")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Drive REST API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters):

> - The `contains` operator only performs matching on entire string tokens for `fullText`. For example, if the full text of a doc contains the string *HelloWorld* only the query `fullText contains 'HelloWorld'` returns a result. Queries such as `fullText contains 'Hello'` do not return results in this scenario.
> - The `contains` operator matches on an exact alphanumeric phrase if it is surrounded by double quotes. For example, if the `fullText` of a doc contains the string *Hello there world*, then the query `fullText contains '"Hello there"'` will return a result, but the query `fullText contains '"Hello world"'` will not. Furthermore, since the search is alphanumeric, if the `fullText` of a doc contains the string *Hello_world*, then the query `fullText contains '"Hello world"'` will return a result.

In [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081419/variable-in-contains#comment89153455_51082475) you mention you tried `searchFiles('fullText contains "IT"' + test)` which does not conform to the required search clause syntax - it evaluates to something like `fullText contains "IT"0` (or `fullText contains "IT"IT0`, depending on if you changed your other code parts) instead of `fullText contains "IT0"`

A good practice when debugging errors in variable-based queries is to first perform the construction (so you can accurately log the query) and then actually do the query:

```
var myQuery = "fullText contains \"" + myVar + "\"";
// var mySingleQuotedQuery = "fullText contains '" + myVar + "'";
try {
  /* use myQuery */
}
catch (err) {
  err.message = "Error using 'myQuery': " + err.message;
  // Log debug info to StackDriver:
  console.error({message: err.message, error: err, query: myQuery, variable: myVar});
  throw err;
}
```

Comment: Oh my God, I was on this page but didn't go that below. Thank You very much, now it is wokring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an escape sequence when you want to add double quotes in your string. So you're string would be: 
'fullText contains \"IT\"'

Comment: I kinda thought was loking for this but unfortunately it is not working. An orginal formula looks like this `.searchFiles('fullText contains "IT2595"');`

Comment: so did you try adding a backslash before your double quotes?